# Is empty implementation of abstract methods a good approach?

Tags: java, android, design-patterns

I'm working with two different Analytics services (Google Analytics and Mixpanel) for my Android app.

I created an abstract base class like so:

```
public abstract class AnalyticsService {

    public abstract void trackAppOpen();
    public abstract void identifyUserOnLogin();

}
```

Then I created concrete subclasses which extended from the AnalyticsService base class.

```
public class MPAnalytics extends AnalyticsService {
    @Override
    public void trackAppOpen() {
        //Send event to MixPanel
    }
    @Override
    public void identifyUserOnLogin() {
        //Identify user with MixPanel
    }
}

public class GoogleAnalytics extends AnalyticsService {
    @Override
    public void trackAppOpen() {
        //Send event to Google
    }
    @Override
    public void identifyUserOnLogin() {
        //Do nothing
    }
}
```

Now Google Analytics doesn't actually support user identification so I had to create an empty implementation of the `registerUserOnLogin()` method.

I feel this probably is not the right way to do it since user identification is not a behavior of Google Analytics and hence it should ideally be not part of the base `AnalyticsService` class and should instead be defined in the `MPAnalytics` class.

But the problem with that approach is on the client, I want to be able to refer to all the different analytics services by using the base `AnalyticsService` class and not worry about the concrete implementation.

```
List<AnalyticsService> analyticsServices;
for (AnalyticsService service : analyticsServices) {
    service.trackAppOpen();
    service.identifyUserOnLogin(); // where should this method be?
}
```

Is there a better way to do this? Thanks.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with an empty placeholder.  You could log something if someone tries to use the method for Google Analytics or maybe throw an exception.

Comment: Java 8 also supports default methods in interfaces. You can define an interface with default empty methods. Reference: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/defaultmethods.html

Comment: Basically I feel it would be better for you GoogleAnalytics class to implement an interface, rather than extend from a class with which it doesnt really have a "is a" relationship.

Comment: Perhaps you could call the method `identifyUserOnLoginIfNecessary` to put more emphasis on the fact that the implementation may be left empty. I'd also use an interface rather than an abstract class if there is no shared implementation details and even if there are you may have an interface implemented by the abstract class. However, if that could be the case with every method then don't bother, it's fine to leave the implementation empty.

Comment: @mdewit Even if I define `AnalyticsService` as an interface, I'll still have the same problem. Although if I define two interfaces, let's say `EventsTracker` and `UserIdentifier` to separate the two behaviors, and make `MixPanelAnalytics` implement both interfaces and make `GoogleAnalytics` implement just the `EventsTracker` interface. That logically makes sense but now on the client I don't have a single type to refer both. Now, instead of a list of `AnalyticsService` in my client, I'll have a `MixPanelAnalytics` and a `GoogleAnalytics` which will cause issues later if I need to add another.

Answer (score 1):

if you can do with interface, do it.
Why --> in case you would have to inherit mother class later for something else.
Don't forget you can inherit just once